# When does magnetic force act as a centripetal force and when doesn't it?

Tags: magnetic-fields, centripetal-force

As the title says, when does magnetic force satisfy $a=v^2/r$? Is it only when the angle between $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{v}$ is $90^{\circ}$?

What happens if there's another force acting on the charge? (i.e electric force), will it still act as a centipetal force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are asking about the interaction of a charged particle moving in a magnetic field, and not the interaction of two magnets:

The force on the charged particle, Q, travelling at velocity $\vec{v}$ in a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ is given by the Lorentz force equation:
$$\vec{F}=Q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}.$$
This force will be perpendicular to the instantaneous velocity and instantaneous magnetic field even when the angle is not 90$^\circ$, but it vanishes if the angle is 0$^\circ$ (or 180$^\circ$).  This means the speed of the particle will not change and the particle will be accelerated initially in a circular arc.  If the magnetic field remains constant, the particle will continue to move at constant speed in a circular arc.  If the **only** force acting on the particle is the Lorentz force from a magnetic field, the path must satisfy the condition $$r={mv^2/|\vec{F}|}.$$

It is the *path* which conforms to the net force on the particle. Observing a path helps describe the acceleration which allows us to infer the net force.  The magnetic contribution to the net force on a charged particle will always change only the direction of the particle. So one might *cautiously* say it will act as a centripetally-directed force. That does **not** mean the particle will execute circular motion!

If you add other forces in, such as $Q\vec{E}$, you can make the particle take non-circular paths such as spirals or straight lines.  If the $\vec{B}$ and/or $\vec{E}$ are time-dependent or spatially varying many other things are possible.

Comment: So when the angle between B and v is anything but 90 or 0 or 180, motion of charge would be helical and in the same time circular motion formula is satisfied right?

Comment: @Just_Cause You must be very careful to handle the vector components correctly, especially if there are other forces you need to consider.  $\vec{E}$ fields which have components perpendicular to $\vec{v}$ can trip you up easily.  Don't go blindly throwing $mv^2/r$ at the magnetic force.

Comment: Sure, but what about magnetic force alone? it would still satisfy mv^2/r in that condition right(acute angle between B and v)?

Comment: Magnetic force along: $qvB\sin\theta$ would be same magnitude as $mv^2/r$. Don't say "satisfy".  that makes is sound like the force is determined by the path. From the path we *infer* the force, but the force arises from electromagnetic interaction. The direction of the force tells you the path will be circular (or helical), The radius of the path is determined by the other parameters, F, m, v, B, $\theta$.